# new/method chaining in PHP

Tags: php

I've written some object-orientated PHP5 code, but it won't parse and I'm not wholly sure why. I've used method chains to simplify a lot of it- and it looks like this

```
$head->AddTag(new Tag('meta')->Extras('http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"'));
```

Apparently, it has unexpected `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`. This seems perfectly valid to me- where's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
new Tag('meta')->
```

sadly, chaining is not valid in conjunction with `new`.

Don't ask me why, I'd like to have it. (Edit: @troelskn explains why. I wasn't thinking.)

You will need to declare `new Tag('meta')` outside the call. Building a generic static factory class that can give you an object should also work, like so:

```
$head->AddTag(Factory::create("Tag", "meta")-> .....
```

An example should look something like this - I'm wussing out and writing a non-generic one, I'm too lazy to write a generic one right now, as that's complex :)

```
public static function createTag($meta)
 {
   return new Tag($meta); 
}
```

Comment: Afaik there is somewhere a proposal discussing this, but the problem is: Does `new X()->y()` mean `(new X())->y()` or `new (X()->y())`? However, I miss this syntactic sugar also.

Comment: @mellamokb I don't think so, he was just meaning it as an example

Comment: Wait, how would one implement Factory::create?

Comment: @DeadMG I added a non-generic example. A generic factory is a bit tougher, it would need to count all arguments it was passed using `func_get_args()` and `func_num_args()`, and pass them on to the constructor of the class to be used.

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, that's what I was trying to avoid, because I have several classes whose constructors could use being chained this way. I will try to write a generic version myself.

Comment: @DeadMG yeah. Interestingly, with a cursory search, I can't see one on SO, but it's definitely possible - if all else fails, using `eval()`, but there *must* be a sane way. (The problem is that `call_user_func_array()` that usually handles these kinds of things can't be applied on a `new` call.) Should you ask a question about that, I'd appreciate if you could post the link here

Comment: @Pekka: This project really isn't worth that kind of time.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid syntax in PHP. The reason for that is that php both has classes and free-floating functions. Thus you could get ambiguous cases, such as:

```
function foo () { return "bar"; }
class foo {}
class bar {}

$x = new foo();
// Is $x a "foo" or a "bar"?
```

If you want chaining, you can create a function and use as a factory. Either as a static member on the class or as a free floating function. I prefer the latter, which reads as:

```
function foo() { return new Foo(); }
class Foo {
  funcion bar() {}
}

// Usage:
foo()->bar();
```

Comment: is it not possible in your __construct to return the instance? i.e. `return this;`

Comment: @Jaitsu no, `__construct` can't return anything

Comment: @jaitsu - Even if you could return from a constructor, which you can't, it wouldn't help as this is a syntax problem and thus happens at parse time, not at run time.